# crashlytics (fabric) Android Studio plugin broken in release 1.24.0

Tags: android-studio, gradle, crashlytics, google-fabric

I'm keep getting:

> Error:Could not determine the dependencies of task
>   ':main:crashlyticsStoreDeobsDebug'.
>   Task with path 'dexDebug' not found in project ':main'.

gradle include:

```
classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1+'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matt from the Fabric team here! This error would occur when using Proguard with debug builds and Instant Run with the Android plugin for Gradle version 2.3.3 and the Fabric plugin version 1.24.0.

Today we released [version 1.24.1](https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#august-15-2017) of the Fabric plugin which fixes this issue.

Comment: Thanks Matt, haven't had a chance to check it out, but I'm sure you guys worked it out.

Answer (score 5):

1.24.0 seems to be a buggy release, [released on August 9](https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#august-9-2017) and claims to fix a bug involving problems uploading mapping files.

Change gradle to:

```
classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.23.0'
```

To prevent gradle from getting the buggy update, until the Fabric team issues a fix.